# Why is the light blowing into one direction?

Tags: texturing, light, emission

This is an imported SVG, I used skin modifier for the thickness and Emission shader for the light. But the light is not surrounding but seems having a direction. Does anyone know why it happens and how to resolved it? Thanks!

And there is the normal.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Curious.. a refraction effect? Could you share a stripped-down version (no need for textures) of the problem on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: only used an emission shader for the texture. It gives me trouble to upload files.